# Convert multiple querysets to json in django

Tags: ajax, django

I asked a [related question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648861/return-multiple-variables-from-an-django-ajax-function)

In this instance, I have 4 queryset results:

```
action_count = Action.objects.filter(complete=False, onhold=False).annotate(action_count=Count('name'))
hold_count = Action.objects.filter(onhold=True, hold_criteria__isnull=False).annotate(action_count=Count('name'))
visible_tags = Tag.objects.filter(visible=True).order_by('name').filter(action__complete=False).annotate(action_count=Count('action'))
hidden_tags = Tag.objects.filter(visible=False).order_by('name').filter(action__complete=False).annotate(action_count=Count('action'))
```

I'd like to return them to an ajax function.  I have to convert them to json, but I don't know how to include multiple querysets in the same json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's simplejson module. This code is untested though!

```
from django.utils import simplejson
dict = {
    'action_count': list(Action.objects.filter(complete=False, onhold=False).annotate(action_count=Count('name')).values()),
    'hold_count': list(Action.objects.filter(onhold=True, hold_criteria__isnull=False).annotate(action_count=Count('name')).values()),
    ...
}
return HttpResponse( simplejson.dumps(dict) )
```

I'll test and rewrite the code as necessary when I have the time to, but this should get you started.

Comment: This won't actually work. You can't serialize a Django queryset like that, because the model instances themselves aren't serializable by the `json` module directly.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the hint! I just re-wrote the code. Now actual lists of dictionaries are created on the fly. It should work - but it's still untested. Maybe it's not the most elegant way ...

Comment: You could use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) instead of building dictionaries that way, specially since if any of the fields are ForeingKey or something it would again return an unserializable object. `json.dumps(list(Model.object.filter().values()))` for example.

Comment: Not sure would this work for example with decimal fields though.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I hacked this a bit, but got a working solution off the comments here.

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old, but using simplejson to convert django models doesn't work for many cases like decimals ( as noted by rebus above).

As stated in the django documentation, serializer looks like the better choice.

> Django’s serialization framework provides a mechanism for
>   “translating” Django models into other formats. Usually these other
>   formats will be text-based and used for sending Django data over a
>   wire, but it’s possible for a serializer to handle any format
>   (text-based or not).

[Django Serialization Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)