# Django Converting Queryset with Foreign Keys to JSON

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to pass JSON objects to my template. I have some complicated relationships that I can't modify. Based on OS
posts I've tried different things. The ones that I think brought me close are:

I created a .values() queryset that looks like this

```
    def my_queryset():
         results=TodaysResults.objects.values('id','foreignModel1__name',
        'foreignModel1__ForeignModel2__title')
        print (myquery_set)
```

my_queryset gives me all the values I need. So I tried to convert it using the methods below.
1)

```
def make_querydict():
    results=TodaysResults.objects.values('id','foreignModel1__name',
    'foreignModel1__ForeignModel2__title')
    json_results=json.dumps(list(results,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder))
    print (json_results)
```

I get the following error:

> "TypeError: list() takes no keyword arguments"

2. I tried this as well:

   def serialize():
   fields = ['id','foreignModel1__name','foreignModel1__ForeignModel2__title']
   qs = TodaysResults.objects.all()
   json_data = serializers.serialize('json',qs,fields=fields)
   print(json_data)

But when I print the json_data in only shows id and not the foreign values.

3. Based on a few answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649820/convert-multiple-querysets-to-json-in-django)(from 2012) that were along the same lines And I tried:

   ```
    def for_JSON_response():
    response=JsonResponse(dict(results_info=list(TodaysResultslts.objects.values('id','foreignModel1__name',
    'foreignModel1__ForeignModel2__title')
    print(response)
   ```

I don't get any errors but it does not print anything.So, I'm assuming nothing happened.

4. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json) I tried:

   def my_queryset():
   results=TodaysResults.objects.values('id','foreignModel1__name',
   'foreignModel1__ForeignModel2__title')
   print (JsonResponse(results, safe=False))
   I get:

> TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable

And I tried:

```
  def my_queryset():
     results=TodaysResults.objects.values('id','foreignModel1__name',
    'foreignModel1__ForeignModel2__title')
     results_json = serializers.serialize('json',results)
```

And I got:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

I've been looking around a lot and some of the responses look outdated. My attempts above are the ones that I believe came the closest to converting the
valuesqueryset to json or getting the values I need into JSON. Is there a way of making a chained query like the one I have in my_queryset and convert it to JSON?

Models.Py
Simplified for this example

```py
class TodaysResults(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ForeignModel1 = models.ForeignKey(ForeignModel,related_name='m1')

class ForeignModel(models.Model):
    name = Models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ForeignModel2 = models.ManyToManyField(M2M, related_name='m2')

class M2M(models.Model):
    title = Models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Do you using `django-restframework`'s serializer [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: I've never used django-restframework. Not that I'm not open to it. It's just that the .values() my_queryset already has all the fields I need and I was even able to rename the 'foreignModel1__ForeignModel2__title' into title using annotate F. Can DjangoRestFramework be used to serialize a queryset?

Comment: Yes, it can. You can safely use it. It will help you do lot of things with minimum afford.

Comment: Ok. I'm reading the link you kindly provided and I see something named 'serpy'? I guess I'm trying to find something that can just take the queryset? My concern is the foreign keys and ManytoMany fields.

Comment: I would like to suggest to read about `ModelSerializer` and i am going to post a answer how django-rest-framework serializer can solve your problem.

Comment: Ok. I greatly appreciate it. Does this mean that I have to convert my app into an API to use rest framework?

Comment: No, you don't have to be. you can add `rest-framework` as an additional app in INSTALL_APP and use it like other app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have three model `TodaysResults`, `ForeignModel` and `MModel` and I am guessing `MModel` is a `manyTomany` relationship with `ForeignModel`. I am proposing two possible way how we can get all information from `TodaysResults` serializer.

### Possible Solution One

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MModel
        fields = ('title',)

class ForeignModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foreignModel2 = MModelSerializer(many=True) # as it is many to many field
    class Meta:
        model = ForeignModel
        fields = ('name', 'foreignModel2',)

class TodaysResultsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foreignModel1 = ForeignModelSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = TodaysResults
        fields = ('place', 'foreignModel1')
```

Now pass your `TodaysResults` queryset TodaysResultsSerializer and from serializer.data you will get your serialized data.

### Possible Solution Two

Even we can do this with one serialize as there is not all fields is required.

```
class TodaysResultsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TodaysResults
        fields = ('place', 'foreignModel1__name', 'foreignModel1__foreignModel2__title')
```

Though i am not fully sure but this should also work.

Comment: you need to pass `TodaysResults.objects.all()`'s queryest for first solution, where you will get your desire fields. and for second one your results should work.